# How to create a model with mixed regression and classification output in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In sklearn, there are MultiOutputRegressor and MultiOutputClassifier. We can use them to output only regression or only classification, but what if we want to output a combination of regression and classification? Do I need to create separate models?

In tensorflow, we can branch the architecture. I would like to do regression and classification prediction in one model in this way.

---

It was also pointed out to me that I need to be more specific about my problem, which I will explain below.

The closest example to the problem I am facing is the following.
It is to predict age and gender from mugshots using the UTKFace dataset.
https://susanqq.github.io/UTKFace/

This problem is a mixture of regression and classification.
In the case of deep learning, we know that with Keras we can use approaches such as
https://machinelearningmastery.com/neural-network-models-for-combined-classification-and-regression/

So, what about machine learning?
I found a reasonable approach in sklearn, but I don't think it assumes the case where regression and classification are mixed.
How can I solve this kind of problem in machine learning with one model?
Or do I need to have more than one model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I see one possible solution using `xgboost` (it supports scikit-learn API). Here the documentation explains how to create [custom objectives](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/custom_metric_obj.html). Assume that we have classification and regression objectives. If they are twice differentiable, we can implement their gradient and hessian functions and combine them into an overall objective:

```py
def gradient_clf(predt, dtrain):
    """Returns f'(x)"""
def gradient_reg(predt, dtrain):
    """Returns g'(x)"""
def gradient(predt, dtrain):
    return gradient_clf(predt, dtrain) + gradient_reg(predt, dtrain)

def hessian_clf(predt, dtrain):
    """Returns f''(x)"""
def hessian_reg(predt, dtrain):
    """Returns g''(x)"""
def hessian(predt, dtrain):
    return hessian_clf(predt, dtrain) + hessian_reg(predt, dtrain)

def custom_objective(predt, dtrain):
    return gradient(predt, dtrain), hessian(predt, dtrain)
```

Then we should pass `custom_objective` to `XGBRegressor`'s `objective` parameter to train the model with our objective. During prediction, for the classification task we either manually choose a threshold for or calibrate obtained confidence scores, and for the regression task we keep the scores.